# Netbeans error creating project ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, netbeans-7

when i'm trying to create a new rails project in netbeans. it gives me following error

```
rake aborted! cannot load such file--
warbler F:/ninto/RubyApplication3/lib/tasks/warbler.rake1:in
'require'F:/ninto/Ruby/RailsApplication3/Rakefile:7:in'<top(required)>'
```

this occurs when i check the option

```
Add Rake Targets to Support App Server Deployment(.war)
```

i'm using netbeans 7.3, rails 3.2.13, ruby 1.9.3p392, windows. Googled through many posts still couldn't find an answer. 
thanks

Comment: You can never google enough ;)

Comment: Are you specifically *trying* to create a warbler/jruby project or are you just checking out what options do?

Comment: @DaveNewton yes.. i was checking out the option of adding rake targets to support app server deployment.. BTW i had uninstalled and re-installed ruby since i accidentally updated to 4.0.0.. till then it was fine... i've installed warbler from netbeans though..